# Show that $f\mapsto \exp(f)$ is (locally) Lipschitz on $H^1(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f,f' \in H^2(\Omega)$ with $\|f\|_{H^2(\Omega)},\|f'\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq M$, $\Omega$ smooth and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. I want to show that
$$\|\exp(f)-\exp(f')\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\leq C(M)\|f-f'\|_{H^1(\Omega)}.$$
Of course this is straight forward in $L^p$-norms since by the mean-value theorem
$$\exp(f(x))-\exp(f'(x))=\exp(\tilde{f}(x))(f(x)-f'(x))$$
for some $\tilde{f}(x)\in [f(x),f'(x)]$. One brute-force way to show the property for the $H^1$ norms would be to find the weak derivative of $\exp(f)-\exp(f')$ and repeat the argument above in $L^2$ norms. However it feels like there should be a simpler way arguing $f\mapsto \exp(f)$ is Fréchet differentiable on a general function space?

Comment: What do you mean by $f'$? $f$ is a 2-variable function. Maybe you mean $\nabla f$

Comment: $f'$ is just a different function...